# is there any way to scrape this website faster with python?

Tags: python, web-scraping

the website is "https://www.diretta.it/partita/ALdJKzeJ/#/classifiche/table/overall" and I use this code with selenium but it takes about 30 seconds, and doing the same operation many times becomes too much time

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
wbe= webdriver.Chrome('/Users/paolopiceni/Desktop/scraping/chromedriver',options=chrome_options)

wbe.get("https://www.diretta.it/partita/ALdJKzeJ/#/classifiche/table/overall")
sleep(2)

TEAM_HOME= wbe.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'duelParticipant__home ').text
TEAM_AWAY= wbe.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'duelParticipant__away ').text

teams_class_totale= wbe.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@class="ui-table__row table__row--selected "]/div[@class="table__cell table__cell--participant  "]')
team1_class_totale=teams_class_totale[0].text
team2_class_totale=teams_class_totale[1].text

print(TEAM_HOME,TEAM_AWAY,team1_class_totale,team2_class_totale)
```

I try the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from time import perf_counter

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")

service = Service('/Users/paolopiceni/Desktop/scraping/chromedriver')

XPATH = '//*[@class="ui-table__row table__row--selected "]/div[@class="table__cell table__cell--participant  "]'
HC = 'duelParticipant__home'
AC = 'duelParticipant__away'
IW = 5

def main():
    with webdriver.Chrome('/Users/paolopiceni/Desktop/scraping/chromedriver', options=chrome_options) as wbe:
        wbe.implicitly_wait(IW)
        wbe.get("https://www.diretta.it/partita/ALdJKzeJ/#/classifiche/table/overall")

        TEAM_HOME = wbe.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, HC).text
        TEAM_AWAY = wbe.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, AC).text

        teams_class_totale = wbe.find_elements(By.XPATH, XPATH)
        assert len(teams_class_totale) > 1
        return TEAM_HOME, TEAM_AWAY, teams_class_totale[0].text, teams_class_totale[1].text

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = perf_counter()
    print(*main())
    end = perf_counter()
    print(f'Duration={end-start:.4}s')
```

but it runs in 41s

```
El Gaish Ceramica Cleopatra Ceramica Cleopatra El Gaish
Duration=41.54s

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from time import perf_counter
import datetime

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")

service = Service('/Users/paolopiceni/Desktop/scraping/chromedriver')

XPATH = '//*[@class="ui-table__row table__row--selected "]/div[@class="table__cell table__cell--participant  "]'
HC = 'duelParticipant__home'
AC = 'duelParticipant__away'
IW = 5

def main():
    with webdriver.Chrome('/Users/paolopiceni/Desktop/scraping/chromedriver', options=chrome_options) as wbe:
        wbe.implicitly_wait(IW)
        print(datetime.datetime.now())
        wbe.get("https://www.diretta.it/partita/ALdJKzeJ/#/classifiche/table/overall")
        print(datetime.datetime.now())
        TEAM_HOME = wbe.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, HC).text
        TEAM_AWAY = wbe.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, AC).text
        print(datetime.datetime.now())
        teams_class_totale = wbe.find_elements(By.XPATH, XPATH)
        print(datetime.datetime.now())
        assert len(teams_class_totale) > 1
        return TEAM_HOME, TEAM_AWAY, teams_class_totale[0].text, teams_class_totale[1].text

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = perf_counter()
    print(*main())
    end = perf_counter()
    print(f'Duration={end-start:.4}s')

I try this, and returns:
2023-06-30 13:28:32.871837
2023-06-30 13:29:01.530982
2023-06-30 13:29:04.029629
2023-06-30 13:29:10.085035
El Gaish Ceramica Cleopatra Ceramica Cleopatra El Gaish
```

so the longest time is after the wbe.get(url) line
so what could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first selenium script runs for 3 seconds on my laptop. But, you can use `requests` & `beautiful soup` to obtain the data without loading the whole site (slow - about 40 seconds on your PC).

This script prints the same as in `TEAM_HOME` and `TEAM_AWAY`.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import re

page = requests.get("https://www.diretta.it/partita/ALdJKzeJ/#/classifiche/table/overall")
page.raise_for_status()

page = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

data = page.find("body").find("script").string
data = re.search(r"window\.environment = (.*);", data, re.S)

data = data.group(1)
data = json.loads(data)

team_home = data["participantsData"]["home"][0]["name"]
team_away = data["participantsData"]["away"][0]["name"]

print(team_home, team_away) # El Gaish Ceramica Cleopatra

# uncomment to explore given data
# json.dump(data, open("data.json", "w"), indent=4)
```

The table is a bit more complicated. I think it comes from `https://local-it.flashscore.ninja/400/x/feed/df_to_1_ALdJKzeJ_1` (make sure you provide the `x-fsign: SW9D1eZo` header) and the output needs to be parsed, but it should be a good start. But I don't understand why you want the team name from the selected row to be the same as the one at the top (`TEAM_HOME`, `TEAM_AWAY`).

### UPDATE:

Finally, I created the parser. The selected rows are in the variables `row_team_home` & `row_team_away` as dictionary. The data you want to retrieve can be pulled up using the keys in the dictionary.

Please share your running time (0.32s on my PC) and please accept my answer if solved your problem.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import re
import time

time_start = time.time()

page = requests.get("https://www.diretta.it/partita/ALdJKzeJ/#/classifiche/table/overall")
page.raise_for_status()

page = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

data = page.find("body").find("script").string
data = re.search(r"window\.environment = (.*);", data, re.S)

if not data: raise ValueError("data not found")

data = data.group(1)
data = json.loads(data)

# uncomment to explore given data
# json.dump(data, open("data.json", "w"), indent=4)

team_home = data["participantsData"]["home"][0]
team_away = data["participantsData"]["away"][0]

print(team_home["name"], "- vs -", team_away["name"]) # El Gaish - vs - Ceramica Cleopatra

event_id = data["event_id_c"]
feed_sign = data["config"]["app"]["feed_sign"]

page = requests.get(f"https://local-it.flashscore.ninja/400/x/feed/df_to_1_{event_id}_1", headers={"x-fsign": feed_sign})
page.raise_for_status()

DELIMETER_ARRAY = "|"
DELIMETER_ROW = "~"
DELIMETER_CELL = "¬"
DELIMETER_VALUE = "÷"

data = page.content.decode()
data = next(filter(None, [[*filter(None, [[*filter(None, [[*filter(None, z.split(DELIMETER_VALUE))] for z in y.split(DELIMETER_CELL)])] for y in x.split(DELIMETER_ROW)])] for x in data.split(DELIMETER_ARRAY)]))

team_home_id = team_home["id"]
team_away_id = team_away["id"]

table = {}
forma = "FORMA"

last_team_id = None

for row in data:
    try:
        row = dict(row)
    except ValueError:
        continue

    if "TI" in row: last_team_id = row["TI"]

    if last_team_id in table: # assume row is forma
        table[last_team_id][forma].append(row)
    else:
        row[forma] = [] # add space to forma

        table[last_team_id] = row

row_team_home = table[team_home_id]
row_team_away = table[team_away_id]

print(row_team_home)
print(row_team_away)

# printed output
"""
{'TR': '14', 'TS': '1', 'TN': 'El Gaish', 'TI': 'rRAQSp3M', 'TIU': '/squadra/el-gaish/rRAQSp3M/', 'TM': '32', 'TW': '7', 'TWR': '7', 'TWO': '0', 'TWP': '0', 'TWA': '0', 'TDR': '12', 'TL': '13', 'TLR': '13', 'TLO': '0', 'TLP': '0', 'TLA': '0', 'TAP': '73.17', 'NRM': '0', 'TPK': '1.03', 'TPF': '-11', 'TG': '30:41', 'TP': '33', 'FORMA': [{'LMS': 'N', 'LMU': 'draw', 'LME': 'ALdJKzeJ', 'LMH': 'rRAQSp3M', 'LMA': 'ATasWtPS', 'LMT': '[b]0:0&nbsp;[/b](El Gaish - Ceramica Cleopatra)\n1688083200'}, {'LMS': 'V', 'LMU': 'win', 'LME': 'xGGr8cBD', 'LMH': 'Q79lCRYM', 'LMA': 'rRAQSp3M', 'LMT': '[b]0:1&nbsp;[/b](Ismaily - El Gaish)\n1686182400'}, {'LMS': 'V', 'LMU': 'win', 'LME': 'b1ZiIsZK', 'LMH': 'rRAQSp3M', 'LMA': 't6WUYDaO', 'LMT': '[b]2:0&nbsp;[/b](El Gaish - Smouha)\n1685750400'}, {'LMS': 'P', 'LMU': 'loss stage-3', 'LME': 'bm8KAoX4', 'LMH': 'Qk0VR4IS', 'LMA': 'rRAQSp3M', 'LMT': '[b]2:0&nbsp;[/b](Zamalek - El Gaish)\n1685404800'}, {'LMS': 'P', 'LMU': 'loss stage-3', 'LME': 'MROX0A3t', 'LMH': 'rRAQSp3M', 'LMA': 'EPsYDm4A', 'LMT': '[b]0:2&nbsp;[/b](El Gaish - Al Ahly)\n1685059200'}]}
{'TR': '12', 'TS': '1', 'TN': 'Ceramica Cleopatra', 'TI': 'ATasWtPS', 'TIU': '/squadra/ceramica-cleopatra/ATasWtPS/', 'TM': '32', 'TW': '6', 'TWR': '6', 'TWO': '0', 'TWP': '0', 'TWA': '0', 'TDR': '16', 'TL': '10', 'TLR': '10', 'TLO': '0', 'TLP': '0', 'TLA': '0', 'TAP': '96.67', 'NRM': '0', 'TPK': '1.06', 'TPF': '-1', 'TG': '29:30', 'TP': '34', 'FORMA': [{'LMS': 'N', 'LMU': 'draw', 'LME': 'ALdJKzeJ', 'LMH': 'rRAQSp3M', 'LMA': 'ATasWtPS', 'LMT': '[b]0:0&nbsp;[/b](El Gaish - Ceramica Cleopatra)\n1688083200'}, {'LMS': 'N', 'LMU': 'draw', 'LME': 'bPHv9wd7', 'LMH': 't6WUYDaO', 'LMA': 'ATasWtPS', 'LMT': '[b]2:2&nbsp;[/b](Smouha - Ceramica Cleopatra)\n1686096000'}, {'LMS': 'N', 'LMU': 'draw', 'LME': 'IiRqK348', 'LMH': 'ATasWtPS', 'LMA': 'UP8rEKaA', 'LMT': '[b]0:0&nbsp;[/b](Ceramica Cleopatra - Pharco)\n1685664000'}, {'LMS': 'P', 'LMU': 'loss stage-3', 'LME': 'CC53RUDD', 'LMH': 'EPsYDm4A', 'LMA': 'ATasWtPS', 'LMT': '[b]1:0&nbsp;[/b](Al Ahly - Ceramica Cleopatra)\n1685318400'}, {'LMS': 'P', 'LMU': 'loss stage-3', 'LME': '2NsYri0o', 'LMH': 'KCzFp0OB', 'LMA': 'ATasWtPS', 'LMT': '[b]1:0&nbsp;[/b](Future FC - Ceramica Cleopatra)\n1684886400'}]}
"""

time_end = time.time()

# Elapsed: 0.32
print("Elapsed: {:.2}".format(time_end - time_start))
```

Comment: I also want to get the name from the selected row because then I also want to get the data of that row, and I didn't understand how to do it, could you give me an example?

Comment: @mario Finally, I created the parser. See the update. Please share your running time (0.32s on my PC) and please accept my answer if solved your problem.

Comment: thanks so much, you solved my problem, now it runs in 0.49s

Answer (score 1):

You may find using the implicitly_wait() function will help. Using hard-coded sleeps is rarely a good idea.

This runs in under 3 seconds in my environment:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from time import perf_counter

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")

service = Service('/Volumes/G-Drive/chromedriver')

XPATH = '//*[@class="ui-table__row table__row--selected "]/div[@class="table__cell table__cell--participant  "]'
HC = 'duelParticipant__home'
AC = 'duelParticipant__away'
IW = 5
URL = 'https://www.diretta.it/partita/ALdJKzeJ/#/classifiche/table/overall'

def main():
    with webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options) as wbe:
        wbe.implicitly_wait(IW)
        wbe.get(URL)

        TEAM_HOME = wbe.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, HC).text
        TEAM_AWAY = wbe.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, AC).text

        teams_class_totale = wbe.find_elements(By.XPATH, XPATH)
        assert len(teams_class_totale) > 1
        return TEAM_HOME, TEAM_AWAY, teams_class_totale[0].text, teams_class_totale[1].text

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = perf_counter()
    print(*main())
    end = perf_counter()
    print(f'Duration={end-start:.2}s')
```

**Output:**

```
El Gaish Ceramica Cleopatra Ceramica Cleopatra El Gaish
Duration=2.7s
```

Comment: I don't now why but it runs in 41 s 
'''El Gaish Ceramica Cleopatra Ceramica Cleopatra El Gaish
Duration=41.54s'''

Comment: Are you using a proxy? Is it slow if you access that URL from a browser? Is your broadband speed suitable for your requirements. You could add some debug prints to show which parts of the code you reach at various time points

Comment: no, i'm not using a proxy, and if i access the site from a browser it's fast,how can i add these debug prints?

Comment: @Mario Well, you know how to use *print()* so you just need to print the current time of day. Import the datetime module then *print(datetime.datetime.now())*